# Python do np.logical_and in parallel like np.max(array, axis=1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D bool array of shape row*col, is there any efficient way to horizontally perform the `AND` operation to the array?
For example,

```
k = np.array([[True, True, False],
              [True, False, False],
              [True, True, True]])
```

The result is expected to be

```
np.array([False, False, True])
```

Both row and col are quite large, and doing `for` takes more than 12 seconds per 5 million operations. I have thousands of this 5-million operations per task, which takes extremely long.

Comment: `k.all(axis=1)`?

Comment: Brilliant!!! This works! Let me compare the speed with the np.logical_and.reduce(k, 1) provided by @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: `all()` will likely be faster because it short-circuits the boolean operation. I'm not sure if `logocal_and.reduce()` does too

Comment: `all` is actually just slightly slower than `logical_and.reduce`, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: Hi, in my test, overall all() is faster than np.logical_and.reduce. Though in some of the calculations, np.logical_and.reduce may take the lead, but for most of them, all() is 0.2e-05 to 1e-05 second faster than np.logical_and.reduce. Tested on M1 Max with Python 3.10 (arm version).

Comment: @Crear how did you test it? My tests showed `all` is slower.

Comment: we are talking about differences among compiled methods.  Why should one be faster?  at least not without digging into the c code?  As for short circuiting that's more likely in the simple flat case than the multidimensional.   But you can explore that with various test cases.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi My [search result](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1efe554c880c0fd32e131da84cbdf7fc29c8c834/numpy/core/_methods.py#L25) indicate that `np.logical_and.reduce` and `np.ndarray.all` are completely equivalent.

Comment: Hi, update. My previous "for loop" is 100 times slower than either .all() or np.logical_and.reduce(). However, numba.njit doesn't support either .all() or np.logical_and.reduce(). With numba.njit, the "for loop" one uses 12 seconds per 5 million operations, while neither .all() nor np.logical_and.reduce() supports njit, and uses 30+ seconds. It was purely njit, in nopython mode, without using prange or multi-cores.

Comment: @jared, I packed the functions and used the following to get the time for returning the reduced mask every time.
```from functools import wraps
def fn_timer_print(function):
  @wraps(function)
  def function_timer(*args, **kwargs):
    t0 = time.time()
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
    t1 = time.time()
    print ("Total time running %s: %s seconds" %
        (function.__name__, str(t1-t0))
        )
    return result
  return function_timer```

Comment: I've added an answer that provides some timings for `all` versus `logical_and.reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reduce](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy.ufunc.reduce) `k`'s dimension by applying `np.logical_and` to the axis `1`(columns):

```
np.logical_and.reduce(k, 1)
```

---

```
array([False, False,  True])
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been some discussion on `np.logical_and.reduce` versus `all`. From my tests, `np.logical_and.reduce` is generally faster (but not by much) than `all`, though they are nearly the same for large arrays.

### Timing Using timeit

Definitions:

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

N = 10
M = 10_000
k = rng.random((N,M)) > 0.3
f1 = lambda: k.all(1)
f2 = lambda: np.logical_and.reduce(k, 1)
```

In an interactive console after creating the definitions:

```py
>>> %timeit f1()
10.2 µs ± 255 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

>>> %timeit f2()
8.98 µs ± 290 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

In a script:

```py
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit(f1, number=100_000))  # 1.1502485000528395
print(timeit.timeit(f2, number=100_000))  # 1.0641808999935165
```

### Timing Using perfplot

Here, I tested again using shape `(N,M)`. I had `N=10` and varied `M`.

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot

N = 10
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda M: rng.random((N, M)) > 0.3,
    kernels=[
        lambda a: a.all(1),
        lambda a: np.logical_and.reduce(a, 1),
    ],
    labels=["all", "and & reduce"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(1, 23)],
    xlabel="M",
)
```

[image]